# How to create direct link between Node.js and android libjingle_peerconnection

Tags: android, node.js, webrtc

I am developing an android app for voice chat and using webrtc in client side and node.js as server. I have successfully being able to stream voice between two peers and used node.js server for signalling.But this method has a huge problem, because webrtc connects directly the peers, when a peer is connected directly to 200 peers, it will use alot of the device's CPU and bandwidth and i want 500 and more peers to be able to voice chat without consuming much bandwidth and device cpu.To reduce the load on cpu and bandwidth usage I thought of creating a streaming link directly with the node.js server and from there stream it to the other peers like that a peer will have a single link that communicate with others.I want to know if there is a node.js module capable of linking with android's libjingle_peerconnection. I have tried node-webrtc and does not work with recent libjingle_peerconnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Android device will not be able to directly connect to hundreds of WebRTC peers; this simply requires too many resources.

You want to look at a media server, like [Kurento](http://www.kurento.org/). Kurento will run on a server, and be able to send WebRTC media streams from one client to many other clients in the manner you describe. You have to write the signalling layer specific to your application, which you can do in node.js similarly to the two client case.

Comment: thanks mattm kurento is what i was looking for. I am going to implement it right away. for those who marked my question as out of topic could simply pass the question because it was specific and thanks once more to you mattm